# how to wrap elements after x items in javascript/jquery loop?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, loops

I'm having a little problem here with javascript looping.

I have a on click method which receives data from json file and puts that content into div.

In jquery ajax success method looks like this.

```
'success' : function(data) {
                items.push('<div class="home-page-slide-item"><ul>');   
        $.each(data, function(i, item) {
            if(!item.noData) {
                if(i % 7 == 0) {
                items.push('</ul></div><div class="home-page-slide-item"><ul>');
            }
                    
            items.push('<li><a href="' + item.link + '"><img src="' + item.poster + '" /><span>' + item.title + '</span></a></li>');
            }
                });
                $("div#" + $.cookie('type') + "-slides .home-page-slides").html(items.join(''));
        }
```

After Every 7 list item it must be wrapped in ul and div tags.
It does wrap, but it also adds first extra div > ul tags before this loop and how can I remove it? How can I reorder in success method "items" array to get the wanted result?

Here is the screen of what I get.

[image: Here is the screen of what I get.]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change

```
if(i % 7 == 0) {
```

to

```
if(i > 0 && i % 7 == 0) {
```

that's because `0 % 7 == 0`

Answer (score 2):

```
if(i % 7 == 0  && i > 0) { //skip first occasion since 0 % 7 === 0

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you checked if(i % 7 == 0) before push. You have to do it after push
try this one

```
'success' : function(data) {
                items.push('<div class="home-page-slide-item"><ul>');   
        $.each(data, function(i, item) {


            items.push('<li><a href="' + item.link + '"><img src="' + item.poster + '" /><span>' + item.title + '</span></a></li>');

            if(!item.noData) {
                if(i % 7 == 0) {
                items.push('</ul></div><div class="home-page-slide-item"><ul>');
            }


            }
                });
                $("div#" + $.cookie('type') + "-slides .home-page-slides").html(items.join(''));
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Isn't 0 % 7 = 0 ? I think you should also check for i = 0 and remove that case somewhat like this :
if(!item.noData && i != 0) {
         ...
      }